# This error appears when I try to compile my document "Command \widering already defined."

Tags: fourier

[image]
My document doesn't compile. I don't know if a package is missing or I mistyped a word.

I can't find the error

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This site operates exclusively in english.  Could you translate your question?  Also, please post your code as text (and highlight and click `{}`).  Images can't be searched, and we can't copy and paste your work.

Comment: It makes no sense to load `lmodern`, `kpfonts` and `fourier` all together. Choose the font with which you want to typeset your document and remove the other font packages.

Answer (score 3):

Loading the package

- `lmodern` tells LaTeX to typeset with the Latin Modern fonts
- `kpfonts` tells LaTeX to typeset with the Kp fonts
- `fourier` tells LaTeX to typeset with the Fourier fonts (based on Utopia)

It doesn't make sense to load all three and that's the cause of the error.

Choose one.